# Make brightness of two images same

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have two images:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

How to make intensities/brightness of one image equal to other?

Comment: You could make the darker one brighter, or the brighter one darker.

Comment: [link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53749/brightness-equalization-between-different-images) [link-To-A-Paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fa46/ab775794339f15e8b84b8b4fe10fa3079ec7.pdf) [HE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) These are some good reads to explore more.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the pictures brightness by following this procedure:

1. Calculate the brightness for each pixel by:

   a. Converting them to grayscale, each pixel will hold a value between 0 and 255

   b. Convert you image from RGB to HSV, where V refers to the brightness
2. Calculate overall brighness (sum of each pixel value divided by number of pixels)

Once calculated the brightness for both pictures, you can adjust it for one to be equal to the second picture.

**EDIT**

I strongly recommend using option 1b, as you will not loose color information, so you can convert back and forth. Using the grayscale variant, you will have to work on a copy of your image data.